# Read csv into a vector with comma separated elements

Tags: r, csv, vector, read.csv

I have a csv document with data, e.g.

```
> data <- read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
> data

          AT      BE     CH     CZ
AT    0       0.00276 0.148  0.109
BE    0.00276 0       0.145  0.112
CH    0.148   0.145   0      0.257
CZ    0.109   0.112   0.257  0
```

How can I read this document into a single vector with comma separated elements, with rows listed after rows? In other words, I need to get a vector like:

0,0.00276,0.148,0.109,0.00276,0,0.145,0.112,0.148,0.145,0,0.257,0.109,0.112,0.257,0

Comment: Please provide sample CSV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're after.

You can use `readLines` to read the file line-by-line; if necessary, concatenate all entries with `paste0`:

```
data <- readLines("data.csv");
long_vector_of_entries <- paste0(data, collapse = ",");
```

Not sure how useful this format would be though.

---

### Update

If you just want all entries in a single vector, you can simply do:

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
as.numeric(t(df));
```

Comment: Thank you @MauritsEvers. Unfortunately the code does not allow to skip the names of columns and rows. In other words, I get a line which lists both rows and columns' names and figures

Comment: Which one of the two approaches are you talking about? It's not clear what your're trying to do. Do you want to concatenate all entries in a numeric vector? Or do you want to concatenate all lines stored in character vectors?

Comment: The first approach is more appropriate I guess, as I look for concatenating all entries in a numeric vector, i.e. c(0,0.00276,0.148,0.109,0.00276,0,0.145,0.112,0.148,0.145,0,0.257,0.109,0.112,0.257,0). Instead with the first code I get: "\"\",\"AT\",\"BE\",\"CH\",\"CZ\",...,0.0443127126959286,0.291108791077406,0.286172501178689,0.0281103155299642,\"BE\"
The example document is at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hm7ui9V5tFI7isjS4gRsvspmnqRxAvFj/view?usp=sharing
Thank you!

Comment: @Anastasia Providing data through some random download link is generally frowned upon around here. Always supply sample data with the question, e.g. using `dput`. Having said that, I have updated my answer; `as.numeric(t(read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE, row.names = 1))` will return a numeric vector of all entries by row.